# Fetching descendant nodes always return null XML C#

Tags: c#

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<modules>
<level4>
<module>
  <name>Programming Principles I</name>
  <credit>20</credit>
  <assessments>

    <assessment>
      <assessment_name>Course Work 1</assessment_name>
      <weight>50</weight>
      <passing>55</passing>
      <obtain>55</obtain>
    </assessment>
    <assessment>
      <assessment_name>Course Work 2</assessment_name>
      <weight>50</weight>
      <passing>55</passing>
      <obtain>55</obtain>
    </assessment>

  </assessments>
</module>
</level4>
</modules>
```

Whilst, getting into `assessment` childs of parent `assessments` it returns null..

using this code

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("module.xml");
var result = xml.Descendants("module")
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("name") == "Programming Principles I");
var assessments = result.Element("assessments");
var assessment = assessments.Descendants("assessment");
foreach(var a in assessment)
{
    a.Remove();
}
```

At this `assessment` variable I am getting null value exception. The LINQ query works fine but the next two lines I am uncertain. I am actually, removing all the nodes present inside `assessments` node.

Comment: `s.Element("Parents").Elements("Child")` Elements and Element.. could be that

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yess, but you get the whole node when the LINQ is executed. It searches in Xml file for node module that has an element name = "Programming Principles I"

Comment: @AliRasheed you're right, my bad!

Comment: @AliRasheed, can you elaborate a bit more. I don't understand what's the problem apart from what AviFarah commented below. I see `assessment` is not null as you claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot remove an item (the item that part of the construct that is being iterated on) in a **foreach** loop.

Your code:

```
foreach(var a in assessment)
{
    a.Remove();
}
```

is the culprit.  You may remove an item in a **for** loop as follows:

```
var la = assessment.ToList();
for (int i = la.Count; i > 0; --i)
    la[i - 1].Remove();
```

Comment: Note that once you've called `ToList()`, you don't need to be careful any more - `Remove()` won't remove the result from the list, so you can just use a `foreach` statement. See my answer for an example - and a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying a lazily-evaluated query while iterating over it is basically dangerous.

Two options:

- Use the [`Remove` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.extensions.remove?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Xml_Linq_Extensions_Remove__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__). Less code, and it'll work! Replace your whole loop with:

  ```
  assessment.Remove();
  ```
- Evaluate the query before you start removing anything, storing the result as a list. At this point, it's fine to use `foreach` because removing the element from its parent won't remove it from the list:

  ```
  foreach(var a in assessment.ToList())
  {
      a.Remove();
  }
  ```

You still have a problem in your code though - you're using `FirstOrDefault()` when finding the module element, which means you're anticipating that you *might* not find it - but you're ignoring that possibility in the next line.

I'd probably rewrite the code to this:

```
var assessmentsToRemove = xml
    .Descendants("module")
    .Where(mod => (string) mod.Element("name") == "Programming Principles I")
    .Elements("assessments")
    .Elements("assessment");
assessmentsToRemove.Remove();
```

You could do it all in a single statement if you want, but the above approach makes it easier to diagnose issues later in the debugger.

Comment: This works too.. I am confused which should I accept as an answer